# Create new file for each row in csv (trouble iterating)

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to iterate over each row in a csv file with python and create new csv files for each row. So my thought process is open the file, and loop through each row and for each row create a file named `n_file.csv` (where 'n' is the iteration), so here is my code:

```
import csv
csvfile = open('sample.csv','rb')
csvFileArray = []


for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '.'):

csvFileArray.append(row)
print(row)
n = 0
n += 1

file = open(str(n) + "_file.csv", 'w+')
file.write(str(row))

print(n)   # returns 1 every time
```

Unfortunately this is not iterating properly (because it is only create a file named `1_file.csv` and overwriting it each time). How can I fix this?

Comment: Fix your indentation so it's clear what the intended indentation is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='.'):
    csvFileArray.append(row)
    print(row)

    n = 0   # << you do n=0 each loop!!
    n += 1
```

so it's better be,

```
for idx, row in enumerate(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='.')):
    csvFileArray.append(row)
    print(row)

    file = open(str(idx) + "_file.csv", 'w+')  # enumerate do same as you want!
    file.write(str(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

You set n to 0 each time, because you declared it inside the loop. Declare it before the for statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
with open('sample.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = '.')):
        with open("{}_file.csv".format(i), "w") as file:
            file.write(str(row))
```